# Can a bubble of vacuum move through space?

Tags: vacuum, relative-motion, space, bubbles

If there are really regions in space where a vacuum exists, I have learned there can still exist [electric and magnetic fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/18776) within. That makes this region then differentiable from the regions around and could probably be pictured as a *bubble in space*.

If that is so how can this bubble move through the surrounding space? Could a vacuum displace matter in its moving direction or even replace it somehow? Or could it even be possible, that the vacuum cannot move at all, because *nothing* cannot move?

Disclaimer:
This could perhaps be a beginners question, but I failed finding answers to it online and that may be, because I do not know the correct search terms. I am untalented in physics. Please do not throw forumlars on me without explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the word vacuum means is an absence of matter. You should consider what it means to talk about a vacuum. In one sense, a perfect vacuum is never found in a large volume, as even in deep space there are particles moving about- Wikipedia states that there are a few hydrogen atoms per cubic meter. In another sense you can consider any gap between particles to be a vacuum.

The idea of a bubble is a misleading one, as a bubble implies some kind of surface which is a boundary between the volumes within and without. Since a vacuum is simply the absence of particles, then in space there is clearly no continuous boundary analogous to the skin of a balloon.

Even where there are no massive particles there are still electromagnetic and gravitational fields which as far as we know pervade all space.

A vacuum could certainly not displace matter, in the sense of pushing it out of the way. A vacuum is an absence of matter- it is not some alternative form of matter.

Comment: @user298427 This answer clearly and concisely explains your query. Perfectly answered

Comment: I am not fully understanding the answer yet. No large volumes, okay. But if there is a gap between atoms and if a measured speed depends on a reference system and speed is required for movement: If I watch from the perspective of another atom in some distance away from the gap: Can this gap "drift away" with it surrounding atoms and if it does: Is it still the same gap? Does having the same properties in all places makes something belong together? Does that mean that vacuum is somehow constant? I am sorry, but that is such a brain fuck for me ;)

Comment: Try to think of ants walking on a surface. The gaps between the ants are continually changing their size and position, but that is really an illusion- the gaps are not physical entities. The gaps are just the spaces where the ants are absence. The surface upon which the ants are moving is not changing either. The only real change is to the position of the ants.